# Quote macro literal string argument inside string

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following macro:

```
`define check(CONDITION) \
  begin \
    if (!(CONDITION)) \
      $display("'%s' failed.", `"CONDITION`"); \
  end
```

And the following expansions:

```
module test;
  initial begin
    `check(0)
    `check(1 == 0)
  end
endmodule
```

They print the following:

```
'0' failed.
'1 == 0' failed.
```

If I have a condition over strings, though, then the macro expansion won't work properly. Concretely, adding the following line leads to a compile error:

```
`check("foo" == "bar")
```

What I would like, though, is to have the following printed:

```
'"foo" == "bar"' failed.
```

Is there a way to write the macro body that would allow this? I would like to avoid solutions where I have two macros, one where strings aren't allowed inside the condition and one explicitly for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with just one macro in SystemVerilog. It would take something like the `qq()` operator in PERL for this to work.

Comment: I take it it's not possible to build such an operator using the language itself. Would one idea be using VPI to parse a system function's argument and return it as a string? I saw that there are some pretty powerful functions for introspection, including source code introspection.

Comment: Doing this with the VPI would be quite complex. And that's assuming tools have implemented all the VPI routines needed.

Comment: For sure, but it might make for a nice exercise. Hopefully my tool wont disappoint either.